# <div id> section not displayed on webpage

Tags: html, css, web

Im trying to get some basic knowledge practicing with free templates, and i ran into this one

https://www.freewebsitetemplates.com/preview/zerotype/index.html

can someone open index in editor and explain to me why adbox isnt displayed on the page.

Comment: Really, answering such a question and talking about adBlock on Programist forum, can get You +1? o_O... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because of AdBlock browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

Open a New Incognito Window and check it. If your site working very well, check your browser extension. If you are using, AdBlock first.